# SQL Server While Loop Insert into different lines

Tags: sql-server, while-loop

How can I make it possible in SQL Developer 2012 using while loop?

If a value is higher than 1,000,000 (one million) split it into several lines.

For example if the value is 2,400,000 it will be in three lines with the following value 900,000 , 900,000 and 600,000 as shown in table 2 below.

Table 1

```
ID | Value
1  | 200,000
2  | 300,000
3  | 1,000,000
4  | 2,400,000
```

Table 2

```
ID | Value
1  | 200,000
2  | 300,000
3  | 1,000,000
4  | 900,0000
4  | 900,0000
4  | 600,0000
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question.

Comment: Unclear.  What value?   Show sample data and desired results.

Comment: where does the number 900 000 , 900 000 and 600 000 are comming from ?

Comment: From the 2,400,000 splited into 3 lines

Comment: Based on what to split? why not 1m+1m+0.4m = 2.4m? Please edit your question to give more information.

Comment: You  have three times the same id. You made a mistake rewriting what you want or you don't understand well how id's work. Either way, you cant have 3 time the same

Comment: Why were you not able to solve this with the available documentation on WHILE loops in SQL?    What did you try and what error did you get?

Comment: Yes. I want the same ID. There is no primary key constraint on the table. I need it to split as from 900,000.

Comment: What did you think of my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if object_id('tempdb..#test','U') is not null
    drop table #test

create table #test (vals int)
insert into #test values (600000),(800000), (2400000)

declare  @count int =0 -- psuedo group counter
declare @i int -- used to contain current row value

declare @prevval int -- used to step through values in table
declare @more int = 1 -- used to create infinite while

-- get the first value into @i
select top 1 @i= vals from #test  order by vals 

while @more = 1
begin
    set @prevval = @i
    select @count += 1 
    while (@i - 900000)>0 
    begin

        select @i -= 900000
        select @count,900000

    end

        select @count, @i

        select top 1 @i=vals 
        from #test  
        where   vals > @prevval
        order by vals

        if @@rowcount =0 -- no more data...
            break
end
```